# sendMessage doesn't work properly (Wearable)

Tags: android, wear-os, wakelock, android-wake-lock, huawei-mobile-services

If I'm sending some bytes using `sendMessage` from Huawei p9 (Android 6.0) into Android Wear (Sony) the messages are not delivered if the screen of handheld device is turned off. The notifications inside wearable are not updated until the screen in the phone is turned on (in 1 minute)! Will `setUrgent` help? I already added the application in "list of granded applications" that can work while the screen is off. The application already works in WAKELOCK state.

Is it a feature for all Android 6.0 and newer devices?

IS IT POSSIBLE TO AVOID THIS? ANY CLUES?

Comment: Well, you can try the `setUrgent()`. Based on this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/PutDataRequest.html#setUrgent()), the setUrgent flags a Dataitem for urgent transport. A subsequent urgent update will remove the delay for pending updates and will not delay pending urgent updates. Note that you should only use `setUrgent()` for DataItems which need to be delivered right away. For more explanation of `setUrgent()`, check this [thread](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/data-items.html).

Comment: It doesnt work. The device is fall asleep. I've found the solution:grand the backgroind processes for ALL Applicationd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've waste 3 days to find the solution
To fix this problem just enable for **ALL** applications
in the preferences:

> protect application with battery saver

Detailed:

> To access this power profiles section
>
> Go to the **System settings**.  (which you can either find in the quick
>   toggles portion of the notification shade by pulling down the status
>   bar on the top portion of the screen) Scroll down to **Advanced Settings**
>   and head on over into **Battery Manager**. Go to **Protected Apps** selection.
>   (This is what you’re looking for here. and this will control what’s
>   allowed to run when the screen is off and what isn’t.)

http://itechify.com/2016/02/01/how-to-fix-missing-push-notifications-on-huawei-smartphones/

Answer (score 1):

I've got a Huawei Honor 6X running Android 7.0 and EMUI 5.0. I was having trouble getting notifications on my Pebble Time after the screen was locked due to Huawei's battery optimization service killing off processes. The instructions provided by Vyacheslav may be applicable to previous OS and EMUI versions, but I couldn't find those options on my particular device. His answer did point me in the right direction, though. The notification problem was one of many that ended up being caused by overzealous power management (thanks a lot, Huawei #sarcasm). Here are the instructions for how I excluded apps from battery optimization on my phone:

1. Open **Settings** on your device.
2. Scroll down the list and select the **Apps** option.
3. Select the **Settings** option (blue cog near the bottom of the screen).
4. Select the **Special access** option under the **Advanced** section.
5. Select the **Exempt from battery optimization** option.
6. Find your app in the list and select it. You will probably need to change the option at the top from **Allowed** to **All apps** in order to see it.
7. Change the setting from **Don't allow** to **Allow**, then select **OK**.

I'd like to mention that you may also need to go into **System > Battery** and change the **Close apps after screen lock** settings for your app. I had already performed this step in a previously unsuccessful attempt to fix the issue. When I have time, I may go back and test to see if both of these changes need to be done or if the battery optimization exclusion on its own takes care of it. In the meantime, if you exclude the app from battery optimization and it's still getting killed, do the lock screen change as well.

Comment: More detailed. But I've wrote the same. Nevertheless thanks